# Creating role and database PostgreSQL not working

Tags: postgresql, osx-snow-leopard

First I run the command:

```
sudo su _postgres
```

Then I run the command:

```
create role mixeddrinks with createdb login password 'password1'
```

But it comes back with:

```
-bash: create: command not found
```

I’m not very familiar with the Terminal and with PostgreSQL so I’m not sure what I am doing wrong I am trying to create a role and a database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> First I run the command `sudo su _postgres`, then I run the command `create role mixeddrinks with createdb login password 'password1'`

You're mixing up shell commands and the `psql` command line.

If you want to use SQL, you need to use the `psql` command. `sudo su _postgres` is an inefficient way of getting a *unix command shell* as the `_postgres` user. It doesn't give you an SQL shell. You can run unix commands like `psql`, `createuser`, etc from the unix command shell. You can tell you're at the command shell because the prompt looks something like:

```
postgres$
```

If you want an SQL shell, so you can run commands like `CREATE USER`, etc, you need to run `psql`. If you want a superuser SQL shell, that'd be something like:

```
sudo -u _postgres psql
```

This will give you a prompt like:

```
postgres=#
```

where you can run SQL commands. Remember that SQL commands end with a semicolon.

```
postgres=# create role mixeddrinks with createdb login password 'password1';
```

Comment: whenever I run 'sudo -u _postgres psql' command it throws an error saying 'could not identify current directory: Permission denied
psql: FATAL:  role "_postgres" does not exist'

Comment: @TylerRice Argh. I want to get everyone who packaged PostgreSQL for Mac OS X into a room, and let the one survivor out when they've sorted it out in there. `sudo -u _postgres psql -U postgres` on your particular weird packaging of PostgreSQL.

Comment: its throwing the same error still... If you don't know how to fix this i'll just accept your answer since it did answer the original question and I'll make another one

Comment: @TylerRice would be great if you could link to your follow-up question, having the same issue.

Comment: @TylerRice did you try either simply `psql postgres` or `sudo psql postgres`? That eventually cracked it for me.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32025141/3583139