# postgres no users or roles, can't create but works with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql, pg

I'm trying to setup postgres on OSX. I was having problems with a rails app ('cannot connect to database') and reinstalled postgres with homebrew. I cannot issue postgres commands from terminal now though:

```
$ sudo -u _postgres psql
Password:
psql: FATAL:  role "_postgres" does not exist
$ brew list
autoconf    libksba     openssl     python      sqlite
automake    libtool     ossp-uuid   rbenv
gdbm        libyaml     pkg-config  readline
libgpg-error    mongodb     postgresql  ruby-build
$ postgresql
zsh: command not found: postgresql
$ psql
psql: FATAL:  database "connorleech" does not exist
```

This command does work though:

```
$ sudo -u _postgres
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user name] [-u
            user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid] file ...
```

After I reinstalled postgresql with homebrew my rails app began working with this `app/config/database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password:
```

Questions:

1. How do I issue `postgres` commands from the terminal?
2. How is rails running an app if I never created a local `postgres` user or database?

Comment: Why do you put an underscore before "postgres" ? Try `sudo -u postgres psql` instead. Or if your OSX user is actually called _postgres: `sudo -u _postgres psql postgres`

Comment: `$ sudo -u postgres psql` gives error:
`sudo: unknown user: postgres`

Comment: In that case: try the second one.

Comment: `$ sudo -u _postgres psql postgres` after my password gives: 
`psql: FATAL:  role "_postgres" does not exist`

Comment: MY bad. Yet another one: `sudo -u _postgres psql -u postgres postgres` EXPLANATION: postgres has it's own administration for users. Which *might* differ from the unix user-adminstration. Your OS has named your postgres-user "_postgres"; in pg it is called "postgres". The database "superuser" is also called "postgres". If no username is given when logging on to the DBMS, the DBMS assumes the system-username ( "_postgres" in your case) which does not exist inside the DBMS administration of users.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed postgres from [here](http://postgresapp.com/) for Mac OSX try this:

1. From root in bash "psql"
2. This will log on in as the user that the app created (in my case this was my mac user name e.g. "jamesbrown")
3. you'll be at a prompt like jamesbrown=#... enter "\du"
4. you'll now see all the roles, mine included jamesbrown and _postgres
5. if you want to add superuser to _postgres, "alter user _postgres superuser;"

Answer (score -1):

From [Homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ):

> **Homebrew is designed to work without using sudo**. You can decide to use it but we strongly recommend not to do so. If you have used sudo and run into a bug then it is likely to be the cause...

Your first idea of using `sudo -u _postgres psql` does not apply to homebrew. I believe it applies to PostgreSQL as packaged by Apple (which ships with OS X Server Edition, not with the desktop version)

The brew `postgresql` package  doesn't need or create users named `_postgres` or `postgres`, it suggests that you run the server under your own OS user.

`/usr/local/bin/psql` alone should successfully launch and connect to your default database if the server is running and there's no other configuration problem.

See also the output of `brew info postgresql`, it gives the required bits of information to start.